# Installed ubuntu 14.04.5 but cannot see it in the hard drive. I just locate it (using something else)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

My problem is that after I installed Ubuntu 14.04.5, I cannot visit through the label that is shown after the BIOS screen (the label is under the label of my Windows 10). Windows 10 is still running well.

The error says Windows failed to start. `File: \NST\nst_linux.mbr. Status: 0x000007b.`

I installed Ubuntu using the method of 'something else', since I want to install it in another hard drive, which is HDD from my SSD where windows 10 is located.
Here is a picture of my disk management, in which we can see disk 0 (C) is the windows drive (SSD), and disk 1 (D) is the HDD where I want to put Ubuntu in.

[image: image of disk mangement]

In disk 1, partition 1 is EFI, partition 2 is `/` mount point ext4 type. partition 3 is swap area and partition 4 is `/home` mount point ext4 type.
And I chose the partition 1 (EFI, also sdb1) as Device for boot loader installation.

But as you can see from the image, all partitions I allocated for Ubuntu are 100% free and I do not know where Ubuntu is. This is the screenshot after I tried to install Ubuntu for many times, and every time I found they are still empty.

My booting configuration is: `UEFI - secure boot off`. I tried using EasyBCD, but got a warning like this:

[image: image of easyBCD warning]

So there is no way to add new entry for Linux option.

Still, I tried using Grub2 for Windows and clicked several operations (which I do not exactly understand), nothing helpful happened. The error is still there.

I have searched a lot instructions and videos online but it seems nobody has the same problem like mine. Really appreciate if somebody can help me here.

Comment: From where did you get the idea that all these partitions are free? Windows just can't recognise Ubuntu’s file systems because it doesn't know how. If you want a more accurate partition read-out use GParted, `sudo parted -l`, or `sudo lsblk -f` from an Ubuntu live system (i. e. boot the installer medium with the boot entry *Try Ubuntu*). Alternatively you can run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) for a full diagnostic of potential boot issues.

Comment: Thanks David! It turned out the boot link in windows boot manager to ubuntu was the one I installed alongside windows and I forgot to delete that. As you mentioned I have (most likely) installed ubuntu to the partitions, it is just windows' problem that cannot recognize the disks. Thus, now the problem becomes to how to create a boot file for ubuntu. I am searching for that solution:)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that ubuntu did not create a boot file. I used a USB based ubuntu (boot from USB driver and try ubuntu), then download a software named bootrepair. Then follow all the instructions by default, the software will create a boot method named GRUB. Finally I can see ubuntu and the windows boot manager in the GRUB when start the computer.